# GoReplay - replay from .log instead of .gor

Tags: http, nginx, tcpreplay

I am looking into [GoReplay](https://github.com/buger/goreplay) as to reproduce part of the production traffic that occurred yesterday.

The traffic I want to reproduce has been recorded with nginx, and I can save it as a .log or .csv file.

From what I can tell from the [replay http traffic docs](https://github.com/buger/goreplay/wiki/Replaying-HTTP-traffic) it is possible to reproduce traffic using a command like:

```
sudo gor --input-file request.gor --output-http="http://localhost:3001"
```

but this requires a `.gor` file.

My question is, **is the reproduction of traffic (using GoReplay) restricted to `.gor` files, or could I use nginx `.log` files to do so?**

If this is not possible, and given that I don't have a `.gor` file describing the yesterday requests, would you recommend creating a file conversion script, to convert the log files into `.gor` files, or can you recommend a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

After asking this question on the GoReplay GitHub page, I got the answer that: 
 * there is no way to reproduce traffic directly from logs;
 * you must use .gor files to recreate the traffic;

Thus, the only way to replay from traffics is to create a .log to .gor file converter.

link to official answer: https://github.com/buger/goreplay/issues/668

Answer (score 0):

I've found that I can use [another package](https://github.com/AppsFlyer/elb-log-replay) to replay the logs I have, as-is, locally. At the same time, you can have goreplay listen for traffic to capture that traffic and save to log files. Then you can run goreplay with those newly created logs, updating the domain and whatever else you need.

Let me know if you want me to provide a step-by-step.